# Squared internally studentized residual over $n-p$ is Beta distributed

Tags: regression, residuals, beta-distribution

Assume a regression model $y = X \beta + \varepsilon$ with $n$ observations and $p$ parameters. Let $r_i$ be the $i$-th internally studentized residual:
$$r_i = \frac{e_i}{\sqrt{\hat{\sigma} (1 -h_{ii})   }  } ,$$
where $h_{ii}$ is the  entry $i,i$ of the matrix of projection $H= X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ to the column space of $X$, $e_i = y_i-\hat{y_i}=y_i - x_i'\hat{\beta}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ is the unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$.

I need to prove that
$$\frac{r_i^2}{n-p} = \text{Beta}\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{n-p-1}{2} \right). $$

What I have tried is using that 
$$ e_i = \frac{r_i}{\sqrt{\sigma^2(1-h_{ii})}} \sim N(0,1)$$
Then $U=e_i^2$ is a $\chi^2_1$ distribution. Also we know that
$$V=\frac{(n-p-1)\hat{\sigma} }{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-p-1}.$$ With this two distributions I tried to use the identity of distributions from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Relation_to_other_distributions) 
$$\frac{U}{U+V} \sim \text{Beta}\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{n-p-1}{2} \right) .$$

But

$$ \frac{U}{U+V} = \frac{r_i^2}{r_i + (n-p-1)\hat{\sigma}(1-h_{ii})}.$$

What am I doing wrong? Any hint or solution to my problem?

Comment: You're using the symbol "$X$" to represent two completely different things in this post. This is confusing. I'd suggest you  replace the random variables you're calling X and Y in your last equation with U and V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had to solve this problem, and hopefully my response can shed some light. (See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396190/do-studentized-residuals-follow-t-distribution/396217#396217).)

The thing that finally made it click for me was to split the problem into two parts: linear algebra vs. probability.
$
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert{#1}\rVert}
\newcommand{\rank}[1]{\operatorname{rank}\left[#1\right]}
$

#### Linear Algebra

To begin, consider the purely deterministic least squares problem for a given $\mat{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mat{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times{p}}$, whose solution
$$
\norm{\mat{e}}^2=\min_{\mat{\beta}}\norm{\mat{y}-\mat{X}\mat{\beta}}^2
$$
corresponds to residual vector $\mat{e}$.

Partitioning the inputs as 
$$
\mat{y} = \begin{bmatrix}\mat{y}_{(i)}\\y_i\end{bmatrix} , 
\mat{X} = \begin{bmatrix}\mat{X}_{(i)}\\\mat{x}_i^T\end{bmatrix}
$$
and solving the related [leave one out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164223/proof-of-loocv-formula) problem
$$
\norm{\mat{e}_{(i)}}^2=\min_{\mat{\beta}}\norm{\mat{y}_{(i)}-\mat{X}_{(i)}\mat{\beta}}^2
$$
gives a residual vector $\mat{e}_{(i)}$, corresponding to the original problem with point $i$ held out.

The key linear algebraic result is that the two answers are related by

$$\boxed{
\norm{\mat{e}}^2 = \norm{\mat{e}_{(i)}}^2 + \frac{e_i^2}{1-h_i}
}$$

where $h_i$ is the [leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)) of the held out point $i$.

(My derivation was not pretty, and is omitted here for the sake of brevity.)

Before turning to the stochastic component, a final linear algebra note is that the residual can be expressed as
$
\mat{e}=\left(\mat{I}-\mat{H}\right)\mat{y}=\mat{G}\mat{y}
$,
where the [hat matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) $\mat{H}$ is purely a function of $\mat{X}$, and $$\rank{\mat{H}}+\rank{\mat{G}}=p+m=n$$
This means that for a given $\mat{X}$, the residual $\mat{e}$ has only $m=n-p$ independent components ([residual degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)#In_non-standard_regression)), as $\mat{y}$ varies over $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mat{e}$ varies over the [null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#The_row_space_of_a_matrix) of $\mat{X}$. Similarly, if we hold $y_i$ fixed, then $\mat{e}_{(i)}$ has $m-1$ independently varying components as $\mat{y}_{(i)}$ varies over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Alternatively, we can *independently* vary $y_i$ over $\mathbb{R}$ while leaving $\mat{e}_{(i)}$ unchanged.

(Formally, $\mat{H}$ and $\mat{G}$ are the components of the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of the $\mat{Q}$ factor in the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix) of $\mat{X}$.)

#### Probability

Now if our right hand side vector is actually
$$
\mat{y} = \mat{X}\mat{\tilde{\beta}} + \mat{\epsilon} ,
\mat{\epsilon} \sim \mathcal{N}_{\mat{0}, \mat{I}\sigma^2}
$$
then as $\mat{\epsilon}$ varies randomly over $\mathbb{R}^n$, the particular data $\mat{y}$ and residuals $\mat{e}$, $\mat{e}_{(i)}$ will also vary, with corresponding Gaussian probability densities.

In this case we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\sigma}^2 m &\equiv \norm{\mat{e}}^2 &&\sim \chi^2_{m} \\
\hat{\sigma}^2_{(i)}\left(m-1\right) &\equiv \norm{\mat{e}_{(i)}}^2 &&\sim \chi^2_{m-1} \\
\rho_i^2 &\equiv \frac{e_i^2}{1-h_i} &&\sim \chi^2_1
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}^2_{(i)}$ and $\rho_i^2$ are independent.

Then the squared *internally* studentized residual corresponding to $e_i$ is
$$
r_i^2 \equiv \frac{\rho_i^2}{\hat{\sigma}^2} =
\frac{\rho_i^2}{\norm{\mat{e}}^2/m} \implies
\boxed{
\frac{r_i^2}{m} = \frac{\rho_i^2}{\norm{\mat{e}_{(i)}}^2 + \rho_i^2}
} \sim \operatorname{Beta}_{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{m-1}{2}}
$$
where the last step follows from the [properties of the Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions).

Similarly, for completeness it is worth noting that the corresponding *externally* studentized residual is given by
$$
t_i^2 \equiv \frac{\rho_i^2}{\hat{\sigma}^2_{(i)}} =
 \frac{\rho_i^2/\left(1\right)}{\norm{\mat{e}_{(i)}}^2/\left(m-1\right)}
\sim \operatorname{F}_{1, m-1}
$$
from the [properties of the F distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution#Properties_and_related_distributions).